# is it possible to make an atribute of a superclass static in a certain subclass?

Tags: java, static, subclassing

So, I have various sub classes of `Store`. and they all have `rent`. problem is one specific subclass has the same `rent` for all instances of the class whilst the other ones can be whatever. That meaning that the class in question, `Quiosque` has a static rent.
is there a way to to make this precise atribute `static` wihle still inhereting `Store`?

Comment: Please, show us your idea of usage. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: i know this is kinda confusing, sorry.

Comment: Sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384171/making-a-variable-final-and-static-in-one-subclass-while-keeping-it-variable-in) from a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

this is the class diagram. rendaFixa is what i called `rent` and renda is just there because i'm still thinking as to what to do about this class. i konw this is confusing, sorry

https://gyazo.com/f0f353885647fc0dd63a8c9b13b47695